# Uninterpreted int Constants in z3

Tags: z3

Is it possible to treat int constants as uninterpreted in z3? For example, treat `tuple(project(t, 0), project(t, 1)) = t` as `tuple(project(t, left), project(t, right)) = t`. Context: my equations are essentially in `QF_UF`, but because they contain int constants I'm forced to use a logic with integer arithmetic which leads to nontermination sometimes.

Comment: how are `tuple` and `project` defined? can you redefine them?

Comment: They are uninterpreted as well. I'm working with a bunch of axioms like the example.

Comment: If so, then why not just make that argument an uninterpreted sort yourself? You can declare uninterpreted sorts in SMTLib.

Comment: That's one solution indeed. However I'm working on an existing codebase, and it would take some effort to rework it, so I wonder if there's a simpler way

Comment: Sure, the name 'Int' should be free unless you specify a logic that defines it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `Int` to be an uninterpreted sort, so long as you set the logic to be something that doesn't define it already:

```
(set-logic QF_UF)

(declare-sort Int 0)
(declare-fun f ((Int)) Int)

(declare-fun i () Int)
(assert (distinct (f i) (f i)))
(check-sat)
```

z3 says:

```
unsat
```

If you add:

```
(assert (= (f 2) 2))
```

then you get:

```
(error "line 8 column 15: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function (declare-fun f (Int) Int) supplied sort is Int")
```

which avoids confusions. (Though the error message is rather confusing to read!)

If you set your logic to be:

```
(set-logic QF_LIA)
```

then z3 says:

```
(error "line 3 column 18: sort already defined Int")
```

so, that works out as well. See Section 4.2.3 of the [SMTLib specification](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf) for details.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very nice! Is `(declare-sort Int 0)` short for `(declare-sort Int)` and `(declare-const 0 Int)`? I can't seem to find the syntax in docs.

Comment: Added link to the SMTLib spec.

Comment: OK, this is not quite what I want. I still want to accept `(assert (= (f 2) 2))`, but just have z3 treat `2` as a symbol. After some searching this should be achieved by setting `arith.solver` to 0 in some integer logic, but the check still hangs.

Comment: That's not possible. An integer literal is an integer literal. The best you can do is: `(declare-const |2| Int)` (note the bars), then `((assert (distinct (f |2|) (f |2|)))`, which will work. There's no other way for you to use `2` as a literal in a logic that doesn't import `Int` as defined by one of the integer logics.